# How to truncate a Vim 'statusline' field from the right?

Tags: vim, statusline

I'm trying to set the 'statusline' option of a quickfix window like this:

`setlocal statusline=%t%.66{'\ '.w:quickfix_title}%=\ %11.(%c,%l/%L\ %P%)`

But when the field `%.66{'\ '.w:quickfix_title}` is longer than 66 characters, its left side is truncated by default. I want it to be right truncated so I can see the beginning of this field.

(I notice that Vim provides `%<` to also truncate from the left hand. But there's no `%>` as a counterpart.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with a solution during writing this question:

Just replace `%.66{'\ '.w:quickfix_title}` with `%{strpart('\ '.w:quickfix_title,0,66)}`

See `h strpart(`

Comment: It's always nice to see that just by formulating the problem, the solution often comes to mind.